# R: `unlist` using a lot of time when summing a subset of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a program which pulls data out of a MySQL database, decodes a pair of
binary columns, and then sums together a subset of of the rows within the pair
of binary columns. Running the program on a sample data set takes 12-14 seconds,
with 9-10 of those taken up by `unlist`. I'm wondering if there is any way to
speed things up.

### Structure of the table

The rows I'm getting from the database look like:

```
| array_length | mz_array        | intensity_array |
|--------------+-----------------+-----------------|
|           98 | 00c077e66340... | 002091c37240... |
|           74 | c04a7c7340...   | db87734000...   |
```

where `array_length` is the number of little-endian doubles in the two arrays
(they are guaranteed to be the same length). So the first row has 98 doubles in
each of `mz_array` and `intensity_array`. `array_length` has a mean of 825 and a
median of 620 with 13,000 rows.

### Decoding the binary arrays

Each row gets decoded by being passed to the following function. Once the binary
arrays have been decoded, `array_length` is no longer needed.

```
DecodeSpectrum <- function(array_length, mz_array, intensity_array) {
  sapply(list(mz_array=mz_array, intensity_array=intensity_array),
         readBin,
         what="double",
         endian="little",
         n=array_length)
}
```

### Summing the arrays

The next step is to sum the values in `intensity_array`, but only if their
corresponding entry in `mz_array` is within a certain window. The arrays are
ordered by `mz_array`, ascending. I am using the following function to sum up
the `intensity_array` values:

```
SumInWindow <- function(spectrum, lower, upper) {
  sum(spectrum[spectrum[,1] > lower & spectrum[,1] < upper, 2])
}
```

Where `spectrum` is the output from `DecodeSpectrum`, a `matrix`.

### Operating over list of rows

Each row is handled by:

```
ProcessSegment <- function(spectra, window_bounds) {
  lower <- window_bounds[1]
  upper <- window_bounds[2]
  ## Decode a single spectrum and sum the intensities within the window.
  SumDecode <- function (...) {
    SumInWindow(DecodeSpectrum(...), lower, upper)
  }

  do.call("mapply", c(SumDecode, spectra))
}
```

And finally, the rows are fetched and handed off to `ProcessSegment` with this
function:

```
ProcessAllSegments <- function(conn, window_bounds) {
  nextSeg <- function() odbcFetchRows(conn, max=batchSize, buffsize=batchSize)

  while ((res <- nextSeg())$stat == 1 && res$data[[1]] > 0) {
    print(ProcessSegment(res$data, window_bounds))
  }
}
```

I'm doing the fetches in segments so that R doesn't have to load the entire data
set into memory at once (it was causing out of memory errors). I'm using the
`RODBC` driver because the `RMySQL` driver isn't able to return unsullied binary
values (as far as I could tell).

### Performance

For a sample data set of about 140MiB, the whole process takes around 14 seconds
to complete, which is not that bad for 13,000 rows. Still, I think there's room
for improvement, especially when looking at the `Rprof` output:

```
$by.self
                 self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"unlist"             10.26    69.99      10.30     70.26
"SumInWindow"         1.06     7.23      13.92     94.95
"mapply"              0.48     3.27      14.44     98.50
"as.vector"           0.44     3.00      10.60     72.31
"array"               0.40     2.73       0.40      2.73
"FUN"                 0.40     2.73       0.40      2.73
"list"                0.30     2.05       0.30      2.05
"<"                   0.22     1.50       0.22      1.50
"unique"              0.18     1.23       0.36      2.46
">"                   0.18     1.23       0.18      1.23
".Call"               0.16     1.09       0.16      1.09
"lapply"              0.14     0.95       0.86      5.87
"simplify2array"      0.10     0.68      11.48     78.31
"&"                   0.10     0.68       0.10      0.68
"sapply"              0.06     0.41      12.36     84.31
"c"                   0.06     0.41       0.06      0.41
"is.factor"           0.04     0.27       0.04      0.27
"match.fun"           0.04     0.27       0.04      0.27
"<Anonymous>"         0.02     0.14      13.94     95.09
"unique.default"      0.02     0.14       0.06      0.41

$by.total
                     total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"ProcessAllSegments"      14.66    100.00      0.00     0.00
"do.call"                 14.50     98.91      0.00     0.00
"ProcessSegment"          14.50     98.91      0.00     0.00
"mapply"                  14.44     98.50      0.48     3.27
"<Anonymous>"             13.94     95.09      0.02     0.14
"SumInWindow"             13.92     94.95      1.06     7.23
"sapply"                  12.36     84.31      0.06     0.41
"DecodeSpectrum"          12.36     84.31      0.00     0.00
"simplify2array"          11.48     78.31      0.10     0.68
"as.vector"               10.60     72.31      0.44     3.00
"unlist"                  10.30     70.26     10.26    69.99
"lapply"                   0.86      5.87      0.14     0.95
"array"                    0.40      2.73      0.40     2.73
"FUN"                      0.40      2.73      0.40     2.73
"unique"                   0.36      2.46      0.18     1.23
"list"                     0.30      2.05      0.30     2.05
"<"                        0.22      1.50      0.22     1.50
">"                        0.18      1.23      0.18     1.23
".Call"                    0.16      1.09      0.16     1.09
"nextSeg"                  0.16      1.09      0.00     0.00
"odbcFetchRows"            0.16      1.09      0.00     0.00
"&"                        0.10      0.68      0.10     0.68
"c"                        0.06      0.41      0.06     0.41
"unique.default"           0.06      0.41      0.02     0.14
"is.factor"                0.04      0.27      0.04     0.27
"match.fun"                0.04      0.27      0.04     0.27

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 14.66
```

I'm surprised to see `unlist` taking up so much time; this says to me that there
might be some redundant copying or rearranging going on. I'm new at R, so it's
entirely possible that this is normal, but I'd like to know if there's anything
glaringly wrong.

## Update: sample data posted

I've posted the full version of the program
[here](https://gist.github.com/3151005) and the sample data I use
[here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19422084/dump.sql.gz). The sample data is the
`gzip`ed output from `mysqldump`. You need to set the proper environment
variables for the script to connect to the database:

- `MZDB_HOST`
- `MZDB_DB`
- `MZDB_USER`
- `MZDB_PW`

To run the script, you must specify the `run_id` and the window boundaries. I
run the program like this:

```
Rscript ChromatoGen.R -i 1 -m 600 -M 1200
```

These window bounds are pretty arbitrary, but select roughly a half to a third
of the range. If you want to print the results, put a `print()` around the call
to `ProcessSegment` within `ProcessAllSegments`. Using those parameters, the
first 5 should be:

```
[1] 7139.682 4522.314 3435.512 5255.024 5947.999
```

You probably want want to limit the number of results, unless you want 13,000
numbers filling your screen :) The simplest way is just add `LIMIT 5` at the end
of `query`.

Comment: `unlist` creates names by default, which can take a bit of time and quite a bit of memory.  The problem is likely when it's called by `simplify2array`, but it's impossible to tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: From the Rprof, I'd say it was the `sapply` in `DecodeSpectrum`, and that a solution is to add `USE.NAMES=FALSE` or replace the sapply with `unlist(lapply(...), use.names=FALSE)` or even `lapply(...)` if it is not less convenient to work with lists rather than matricies.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I've uploaded the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/3151005) and the data that I'm using [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19422084/dump.sql.gz). The data is a `gzip`ed SQL output from `mysqldump`. You configure the connection by setting the environment variables `MZDB_HOST`, `MZDB_DB`, `MZDB_USER`, and `MZDB_PW`.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, you also have to specify a `run_id`, which, if you are importing the file I provided, will be 1. Also, to test setting the window, you can set the upper and lower window bounds. All together, I call the script with `Rscript ChromatoGen.R -i 1 -m 600 -M 1200 -b 10`

Comment: @MartinMorgan Adding `USE.NAMES=FALSE` to `sapply` didn't seem to change things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!

The problem was in the `sapply()` call. `sapply` does a fair amount of
renaming and property setting which slows things down massively for arrays of
this size. Replacing `DecodeSpectrum` with the following code brought the sample
time from `14.66` seconds down to `3.36` seconds, a 4-fold increase!

Here's the new body of `DecodeSpectrum`:

```
DecodeSpectrum <- function(array_length, mz_array, intensity_array) {
  ## needed to tell `vapply` how long the result should be. No, there isn't an
  ## easier way to do this.
  resultLength <- rep(1.0, array_length)

  vapply(list(mz_array=mz_array, intensity_array=intensity_array),
         readBin,
         resultLength,
         what="double",
         endian="little",
         n=array_length,
         USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}
```

The `Rprof` output now looks like:

```
$by.self
               self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"<Anonymous>"           0.64    19.75       2.14     66.05
"DecodeSpectrum"        0.46    14.20       1.12     34.57
".Call"                 0.42    12.96       0.42     12.96
"FUN"                   0.38    11.73       0.38     11.73
"&"                     0.16     4.94       0.16      4.94
">"                     0.14     4.32       0.14      4.32
"c"                     0.14     4.32       0.14      4.32
"list"                  0.14     4.32       0.14      4.32
"vapply"                0.12     3.70       0.66     20.37
"mapply"                0.10     3.09       2.54     78.40
"simplify2array"        0.10     3.09       0.30      9.26
"<"                     0.08     2.47       0.08      2.47
"t"                     0.04     1.23       2.72     83.95
"as.vector"             0.04     1.23       0.08      2.47
"unlist"                0.04     1.23       0.08      2.47
"lapply"                0.04     1.23       0.04      1.23
"unique.default"        0.04     1.23       0.04      1.23
"NextSegment"           0.02     0.62       0.50     15.43
"odbcFetchRows"         0.02     0.62       0.46     14.20
"unique"                0.02     0.62       0.10      3.09
"array"                 0.02     0.62       0.04      1.23
"attr"                  0.02     0.62       0.02      0.62
"match.fun"             0.02     0.62       0.02      0.62
"odbcValidChannel"      0.02     0.62       0.02      0.62
"parent.frame"          0.02     0.62       0.02      0.62

$by.total
                     total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
"ProcessAllSegments"       3.24    100.00      0.00     0.00
"t"                        2.72     83.95      0.04     1.23
"do.call"                  2.68     82.72      0.00     0.00
"mapply"                   2.54     78.40      0.10     3.09
"<Anonymous>"              2.14     66.05      0.64    19.75
"DecodeSpectrum"           1.12     34.57      0.46    14.20
"vapply"                   0.66     20.37      0.12     3.70
"NextSegment"              0.50     15.43      0.02     0.62
"odbcFetchRows"            0.46     14.20      0.02     0.62
".Call"                    0.42     12.96      0.42    12.96
"FUN"                      0.38     11.73      0.38    11.73
"simplify2array"           0.30      9.26      0.10     3.09
"&"                        0.16      4.94      0.16     4.94
">"                        0.14      4.32      0.14     4.32
"c"                        0.14      4.32      0.14     4.32
"list"                     0.14      4.32      0.14     4.32
"unique"                   0.10      3.09      0.02     0.62
"<"                        0.08      2.47      0.08     2.47
"as.vector"                0.08      2.47      0.04     1.23
"unlist"                   0.08      2.47      0.04     1.23
"lapply"                   0.04      1.23      0.04     1.23
"unique.default"           0.04      1.23      0.04     1.23
"array"                    0.04      1.23      0.02     0.62
"attr"                     0.02      0.62      0.02     0.62
"match.fun"                0.02      0.62      0.02     0.62
"odbcValidChannel"         0.02      0.62      0.02     0.62
"parent.frame"             0.02      0.62      0.02     0.62

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 3.24
```

It's possible that some additional performance could be squeezed out of messing
with the `do.call('mapply', ...)` call, but I'm satisfied enough with the
performance as is that I'm not willing to waste time on that.